# Nudge feature implemented or dropped?

Tags: discussion, chat

I remember reading a long while (few months? more than a year? not sure...) that a nudge feature would be implemented to get people's attention. The reason invoked was something along the lines of "Private Messaging is Spam" and "Social Interactions are better done on Facebook than StackExchange".

So, does that feature exist? If yes... where is it hidden please?
If not, is this still a plan or has it been dropped?

Right now, it seems the only way to "reliably" signal to someone to come to a chatroom is to "spam" (as in repeatedly adding comments on an answer or comment), in order to be presented with the "move discusssion to chatroom" option.

Evidently, either I'm missing something, or the nudge feature exists, or the current mechanism needs a nudge feature.

By the way, I'm NOT talking of [this type of nudge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28662/nudge-feature) at all!

Comment: That nudge feature was evoked in an answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57203/private-messages-will-stackchat-reopen-the-debate

Comment: You can create a chat room and paste the link as a comment at any time. It just isn't automated until the site believes you're engaging in discussion anyway.

Comment: Nudge nudge, know what I mean, eh?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `@displayname` someone if they've been in a room sometime in the last two days (even if they're not currently in there). Moderators have the ability to alert someone even if they haven't been in the room recently (or been to chat at all), but since it's a mod-only ability I assume there was concern about people abusing it

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to tell if Jeff is referring to something like that or inviting a user to a room, but in either case I imagine they consider this feature covered.