# How to make sure I'll be pingable in chat for a few days?

Tags: support, chat, ping

Let's say I want people to be able to ping me in a certain chat room for a few days.

Do I have to actually say something there, or is it enough to simply join the room? And do I remain pingable even after closing the room? If yes, for how long? And for how long if I said something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once you join a chat room, you can be pinged as long as you are in the room. It only gets complicated when you leave the room:

- If you never post in that room, you won't be pingable
- If you do ever post something in the room, you will be pingable for 7 days after leaving.

Leaving means either you manually click "leave", or when the system detects you're no longer in the room, e.g. your browser tab/window of the room is closed

So to make sure you are pingable for few days, just post something when joining. A "hello" will suffice.

<sup>[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321320/if-a-users-avatar-shows-in-a-chat-room-but-they-dont-say-anything-can-they-be#comment1052404_321320)</sup>

Answer (score 12):

If I recall correctly, you can be @pinged for a week since your last visit to the room (even if you're not currently present among the room visitors), supposing that you ever posted in that room. Note that replying to your message (with the special reply button) would ping you anyway, even you haven't visited for a year.

E.g., I haven't been in Shadow's Den recently (for two days, I think) and neither I do appear among the users [who are in the room now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvXiv.png), and here's the recent notification:

> [image]

Comment: I don't think this is true. I *never* click leave, I just close the browser window (or tab) and I do remain in the room for some time but I know I'm never still in the room the next day (certainly not a week later).

Comment: @Cai How would you know that?.. You've been pinged and not receiving the notification?

Comment: 1. because when I open the room again it shows me joining the room and 2. I regularly check who is in chat without joining and 3. I don't get pinged

Comment: Yes. I open chat at least once a day and *never* explicitly click "leave" and I don't get notifications from @mentions when the room isn't open

Comment: @Cai you may not be in the room, but you still get the pings. If you didn't get the pings, it's for another reason. I leave (not by clicking "leave") everyday after I close my tabs, and the next day my inbox is full of messages from different chatrooms.

Comment: I do get the pings when I come back to chat and I do get the notifications eventually (sometimes only when I rejoin chat, sometimes a few hours later), my point was that I don't stay in the room even though I don't click "leave". If that isn't how it should be working i'd be interested to find out why.

Comment: @Cai See the edit, you don't have to be present among the users who are in the room, you're just "sleeping" if closed the tab.

Comment: You don't stay "in a room" for a week even with your browser closed: if chat detects that you left - either with clicking "leave" or without - chat will remove you from the list of active users. However, if you posted a message, you'll still be pingable for a few days (and get an inbox notification).

Comment: @Program Those "few days" is certainly a week. And I don't think you should post anything, just visit...

Comment: @nicael as I said i regularly check the "currently in room" without joining the room and I'm not there (i.e. not "sleeping") even though I never click "leave". Seems there is some inconsistency in how chat removes inactive users. I'm going to test this out now and see how long I stay "sleeping" in a room

Comment: @nicael Yeah, I meant a week. About the 'posting' vs. 'visiting', I'm not sure. I can't find an official reference about it.

Comment: BTW, just found out I don't get instant chat notifications if I'm not in the room because there is a chat user pref for quicker notifications that I didnt have on :)

Comment: @Cai so you didn't :)

Comment: not an English native speaker so I'm not sure "supposing that you ever posted in that room" means "you'll be pingable even you haven't posted it yet", or "you'll be pingable supposing you have posted there once". Can you confirm?