# If a user's avatar shows in a chat room but they don't say anything, can they be pinged?

Tags: support, chat, ping

I know that a user can only be pinged if they join a chatroom, but I'm not sure if that means they have to say something first or not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that they can be. If their name is in the tab-complete list, then yes.

Comment: @Alex not an English native speaker so I'm not sure "supposing that you ever posted in that room" in the answer of that question means "you'll be pingable even you haven't posted it yet", or "you'll be pingable supposing you have posted there once". Can you confirm?

Comment: AFAIK, from the ping-master Shadow Wizard, you can be pinged the moment you enter a chat room for the first time. Also, that's how some room owners/users/bots welcome a new user who just joins a chat room.

Comment: @Ooker I'm pretty sure I've pinged users who just entered without ever having spoken. But it shouldn't be hard to test, in any case. Pick any room you haven't ever spoken in and enter it. Leave a link here in a comment and I'll ping you and you can see if you get it.

Comment: @Alex: thanks for your help. Here is a link: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/139/lets-get-philosophical But in the case of reading the script of it, then it doesn't count as joining that chat room, right?

Comment: @Ooker the basics are simple. Once you join a chat room, you can be pinged as long as you are in the room. It only gets complicated when you leave the room, either manually by clicking "leave" or automatically by the system when it detects you're no longer in the room, e.g. closed your browser tab/window. In such case, if you never posted in that room, you **won't be pingable**. If you did ever post something in the room, ever 10 years ago, you will be pingable for 7 days after leaving, i.e. anyone can `@-ping` you in the room even when you're not in there. :)

Comment: You are now not pingable in the "Let's get philosophical" room because you left it by now, and never posted.

Comment: @Shadow wish you were here sooner. If possible, can you answer the other question? Split it by cases for readability.

Comment: @Ook what other question?

Comment: @Ooker The transcript does not count as the room itself.

Comment: @ShadowWizard the duplicate one. If you feel too busy I can do that instead

Comment: @Ooker sorry, I don't understand. There is already a correct answer on the duplicate question.